# If a folder contains the ampersand (&) character, why is the symbol stripped from the title bar of Windows/File Explorer?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, files-folders

Since Windows 7, I've noticed that when navigating into a folder that contains the ampersand (`&`) character using Windows Explorer, the character is stripped from the title bar of the window and a space used in its place.

Why is this the case - is this a limitation of Explorer, or something else entirely?

Comment: I am not a Windows person but it seems like the issue is the way Windows Explorer deals with the ampersand character which is ofter used for HTML entities and an escape character in many cases. Generally `&` is considered a reserved character in HTML only. But Windows Explorer is not a web page, correct? My guess is Windows Explorer still has some HTML restrictions in place for some reason. Read up on how [HTML entities](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Entity) work. Maybe create a folder with `&amp;` in it. It might show an `&` or it might show `amp;`.

Comment: Hmm, I don't notice this behavior on Windows 7 or Windows 10. Could you show a screenshot of where it occurs?

Comment: @Giacomo1968: The Explorer window overall is not a web page. Though in Windows 98 up to XP, the main content area below the address bar _was_ indeed a web page (and in Win98/2000 you could even completely customize the HTML template for each individual folder), and it's not impossible that some oddities from that era might have remained. I would be surprised if that was the cause of this problem though; even in HTML or XML, replacing ampersands with a space seems particularly silly when they could have been replaced with an `&amp;` instead.

Comment: I also don't see this behavior on Windows 7 or 10. Does it happen when booting in Safe mode?

Comment: ...have you customized the GUI fonts in any way? Does this issue also affect e.g. the file search bar, or other places which use the same font?

Comment: Could you please upload a screenshot ? I have tested in my windows 10 and I did not find such behavior as well. You might check if the same third party software is installed on your windows 7 and windows 10 machine.